# Fatal error: Directive 'asp_tags' - Installtion of composer using command prompt PHP in windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I am trying to install composer in command prompt with:

`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');`

My installation instructions: https://getcomposer.org/download/

The above command returns this error:

`"Fatal error: Directive 'asp_tags' is no longer available in PHP in Unknown on line 0"`.

I am using XAMPP with PHP version `7.2.x` in my `E:` drive of desktop.

Please help to me solve this problem.

Comment: Made question more readable.